# invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive] strcpy(choice,argv[1]);

Tags: c

Operation on rational numbers, i've to get input both from stdin and command line. When I try to cpy the argv value to variables I get the error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]    strcpy(choice,argv[1]);

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    typedef struct rational
    { int num,den;} Rational; 
    Rational rationalNumMain(int argc, const char** argv)
    {
        Rational r1,r2,r;char choice;
        if(argc==1)
        {
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        scanf("%d",&r1.num);
        scanf("%d",&r1.den);
        scanf("%d",&r2.num);
        scanf("%d",&r2.den);
        }
        else
        {  strcpy(choice,argv[1]);
        strcpy(r1.num,argv[2]);
        strcpy(r1.den,argv[3]);
        strcpy(r2.num,argv[4]);
        strcpy(r2.den,argv[5]);
        }
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 'A':
    r.num=(r1.num*r2.den)+(r1.den*r2.num);
    r.den=(r1.den*r2.den);
    return r;
    break;
    case 'S':
    r.num=(r1.num*r2.den)-(r1.den*r2.num);
    r.den=(r1.den*r2.den);
    return r;
    break;
    case'M':
    r.num=(r1.num*r2.num);
    r.den=(r1.den*r2.den);
    return r;
    break;
    case 'D':
    r.num=(r1.num*r2.den);
    r.den=(r1.den*r2.num);
    return r;
    break;
   } }
    int main(int argc, const char** argv)
    {
    Rational r1,r2,result;
    result=rationalNumMain(argc, argv);
    printf("%d,%d", result.num, result.den);//prints the output
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can't use `strcpy` to convert a string to a number. You need to use a parsing function like `atoi()`.

Comment: You can use `sscanf` to parse numbers from a string, just like you use `scanf` to parse from stdin.

Comment: please, for human readibility and ease of documentation:  1) consistently indent the code (never use tabs for indenting) Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'  2) only declare one variable per line.  3) insert a blank line between code blocks

Comment: when using argv[] and argc  always check argc to assure the proper number of parameters are present on the command line before accessing argv[].   If the proper number of parameters on the command line are not present, then display a 'usage' statement and exit.  In this case, the value of argc must be 1 or 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sscanf` to parse the inputs from `argv`.

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%c", &choice);
sscanf(argv[2], "%d",&r1.num);
sscanf(argv[3], "%d",&r1.den);
sscanf(argv[4], "%d",&r2.num);
sscanf(argv[5], "%d",&r2.den);
```

Answer (score 0):

'choice' is declared as a char not as a char* so this will fail

```
strcpy(choice,argv[1]);
```

since strcpy takes two string pointers as arguments.

in order to take the first character from argv dereference it

```
choice = *argv[1];
```